# Como ocultar apenas 1 formulário da aplicação em c#

Tags: c#

Boa tarde galera!

Estou quebrando a cabeça para ocultar um **formulário em específico**.

Tenho uma aplicação com 3 formulários:

Form1 (é o principal),
Form2,
Form3,

O problema é o seguinte:
Dentro do Form1(principal) eu vou abrir o "Form2" e dentro deste eu vou abrir o "Form3". Quando eu abrir o "Form3", quero que apenas o "Form2" fique oculto e/ou invisivel.

Quando executo o comando Hide() ou Visible, os forms (Form1 e Form2) ficam ocultos (hide) ou invisivel (visible).

Meu código:

> > Dentro do Form1:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (new Form2()).ShowDialog();
    }
```

> > Dentro do Form2:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        (new Form3()).ShowDialog();
    }
```

Se alguém puder me auxiliar, agradeço!

Comment: o problema é que está criando muitos formulários e não está guardando as suas instancias em variáveis para poder esconder um em específico, então precisa procurar todos os forms abertos e fechar o que precisa. Use `Application.OpenForms` para encontrar os formulários abertos e feche/esconda o que precisar

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Ricardo, poderia me ajudar com um exemplo?

Comment: Sim, eu escrevi uma resposta explicando melhor

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que está criando muitos formulários e não está guardando as suas instancias em variáveis para poder esconder um em específico, assim por exemplo:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
```

E podia expor a variável em uma propriedade para poder esconder.

No seu caso é possível obter a lista de todos os formulários abertos usando [`Application.OpenForms`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

`OpenForms` é uma coleção, então para encontrar por exemplo o `Form1`, pode fazer assim:

```
Application
  .OpenForms
  .OfType<Form1>()
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Com isso pode validar se "existe". Note que o `FirstOrDefault()` vai retonar a primeira instância do formulário do tipo `Form1`, se houver mais de uma será retonada a primeira. Para pegar todas as instâncias, basta remover o `FirstOrDefault`, mas terá uma lista e precisará fazer um `foreach` para fechar todos. Para o seu exemplo o `FirstOrDefault` deve funcionar bem, ficando assim o código:

```
var form1 = Application
    .OpenForms         // Obtem os formulários abertos
    .OfType<Form1>()   // do tipo "Form1", o primeiro fomrulário
    .FirstOrDefault(); // Obtém o formulário, se estiver aberto

var form2 = Application
    .OpenForms
    .OfType<Form2>()
    .FirstOrDefault();

// verifica se não é null, ou seja, se existe
if (form1 != null)
{
    form1.Hide();
}

if (form2 != null)
{
    form2.Hide();
}

(new Form3()).ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Ricardo, infelizmente não funcionou...

Continua ocultando todos os formulários.

Comment: eu testei aqui e funcionou local, deve estar fazendo algo de errado

Comment: eu repliquei todo o seu código como está na pergunta, e o código acima está no Form2, ao abrir o Form3, e os nomes dos forms não Form1, Form2 e Form3

Answer (score -2):

Você pode também fazer algo como:

this.hide()
New form1(this).show

No método construtor do form1:

Public form1(Form2 frm) {}...

Passando o objeto o outro formulário e manipulando da forma que deseja.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).